# Why do we still get sharp scattering spots with quasi-crystal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography, quasicrystals

In a quasi-crystal, there is no translational invariance. This means there is no delta-function in the Fourier transform. 
But to get a sharp scattering spot, we need a delta function.

Physically, in a crystal, we get sharp scattering spots because it is possible to get all the scattering waves from each cell in phase. But for a quasi-crystal, apparently, this is impossible.

Comment: Did you have a particular system in mind?

Comment: No concrete system.

Comment: Closely related: [Why do quasicrystals have well-defined Fourier transforms?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82841/8563)

Answer (score 1):

A quasi-crystal has no long-range translational symmetry, but it *does* have long range *orientational* symmetry. The lattice sites all occur at well defined angles, and in well-defined *planes*.  It is reflection from these planes that causes the well-defined spots.  The fact that there is no translational symmetry within those planes does not bear on the interference phenomena perpendicular to the plane.  A collimated ("spot") input beam will be reflected into a collimated "spot" output beam.